# Why does getText() return an empty string even if the text field is not empty?

Tags: java, textfield

For context I am creating a button wherein when player presses it, it gets the text in the text area and does its thing

```
/**
 * Creates and displays the name input Confirm button
 * @param nameInputActionListener The action to be done when confirm button is pressed
 */
public void createAndDisplay_nameInputConfirmButton(ActionListener nameInputActionListener)
{
    this.nameInputConfirmButton = new JButton("Confirm");
    this.nameInputConfirmButton.addActionListener(nameInputActionListener);
    this.nameInputConfirmButton.setBounds(1250, 340, 100, 50);
    this.characterCreationScreenFrame.add(this.nameInputConfirmButton);
}
```

```
this.nameInputArea = new JTextField(40);
this.nameInputArea.setBounds(950, 350, 250, 30);
this.nameInputArea.setToolTipText("Enter Name here!");
this.characterCreationScreenFrame.add(this.nameInputArea);
```

```
/**
 * @return The text inputted by player in the name input text area
 */
public String getNameInputtedByPlayer()
{
    return this.nameInputArea.getText();
}
```

I tried doing the same concept of implementation as taught in a YouTube video and it works, so I don't understand why this wouldn't. The main issue is `getText()` does not retrieve anything.

here is the action listener of it

```
/**
 * Creates the action associated with the Name Input button. Moreover, it temporarily hides the character creation buttons.
 */
private void create_ActionFor_NameInputButton()
{
    // NOTE! dinispose NOT HIDE kasi para kapag player goes back to charac screen gagawa ulit new gui para updated yung current charac details
    characterCreationScreenView.hide_CharacterCreationScreenChoicesList();
    characterCreationScreenView.createAndDisplay_NameInput();
    
    // ACTION TO BE DONE KAPAG NAGCONFIRM SI PPLAYER AFTER INPUTTING A NAME 
    ActionListener nameInput_ActionListener = new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent nameInput)
        {        
                // gets the text na nilagay sa text area and checks if it valid (at least > 1) IF OO TRIM NAME IN CASE EXCEEDING 25
                if(characterCreationScreenModel.checkIfNameInputIsValid(characterCreationScreenView.getNameInputtedByPlayer()) == true)
                {                        
                   String validatedName = characterCreationScreenModel.remove_CharactersExceeding25(characterCreationScreenView.getNameInputtedByPlayer());
                   characterCreationScreenModel.setPlayerName(validatedName);
                   characterCreationScreenView.hide_DisplayNameInput();
                   characterCreationScreenView.unhide_CharacterCreationScreenChoicesList();
                   characterCreationScreenView.createAndDisplay_CurrentCharacterDetailsLabels();
                }
                else
                {
                    characterCreationScreenView.display_NameInputErrorMessage(); 
                    System.out.println("" +characterCreationScreenView.getNameInputtedByPlayer().length());

                }
                

            
        }
    };
    //characterCreationScreenView.createAndDisplay_nameInputConfirmButton(nameInput_ActionListener);
    characterCreationScreenView.createAndDisplay_nameInputConfirmButton(nameInput_ActionListener);


}
```

here is the example output:
[image]

Comment: Are you able to share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: At the very least, edit your question and show us the code of the method which calls `getNameInputtedByPlayer()`.  Are you calling it when you create the window, or are you calling it from an ActionListener?

Comment: i am calling it from the the action listener as the name inputted by player will be validated when player chooses to press said button

Comment: public boolean checkIfNameInputIsValid(String playerNameInput)
    {
      boolean isValid = false;

       if(playerNameInput.length() >= 1)
       {
          isValid = true;
       }
       
       return isValid;
    }

Comment: Again, you will want to create and post your [mre] with your question.

Comment: Also, make sure you are not catching exceptions/errors and hiding them, always print the stack trace. There is a chance that your code is throwing a NullPointerException exception because your code is not referencing the correct text area, but we can't tell if we can't see the relevant code.

Comment: if the text field is not empty but `getText()` is returning an empty string, it is not being called on that text field, maybe on a different instance of a text field

Comment: It appears that Kyle has abandoned this question and so we may never know for sure the cause of his problems.